# Scylla DB latency increasing after every 15 days

Tags: database, cassandra, latency, scylla

Usually, the read latency is around 3-4 ms but after every 15-20 days latency shoots up to 100-150 ms, and because of this I need to restart our whole cluster. The read-repair runs every midnight. I am unable to figure out the issue.

I have an 8-node Scylla cluster (version 4.1). All nodes are within the same data center. In that, I have 5 key spaces.

Out of 5 keyspaces in 3 keyspaces, I am storing JSON blob after compressing it and I am querying on **CL = LOCAL_QUORUM for both reads and writes**. For these keyspaces, the read and write ratio is fairly the same and 6months TTL is set for each record inserted. Each keyspace has only 1 table.

For the other 2 keyspaces, I am storing some internal configs and I am writing the tables using **CL = ALL and reading them using CL = LOCAL_ONE**. The read writes ratio is 10:1 and no ttl is set for the record inserted. Each keyspace has around 5-8 tables.

Below is the configuration of all tables/keyspace:

```
Replciation factor = 3,
compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'},
compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'},
crc_check_chance = 1.0,
dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1,
default_time_to_live = 0,
gc_grace_seconds = 864000,
max_index_interval = 2048,
memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0,
min_index_interval = 128,
read_repair_chance = 0.0,
speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
```

In below graph I restarted the cluster on 5th may and from 5th May till 20th May the read latency was around 3-4 ms but from 20th may onwards it started increasing in an exponential manner and on 23rd when it reached 100-150 ms I have restarted the cluster and read latency was back to normal.

[Latency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxwNm.png)

I suspect seeing the below graph that the increase in latency might be due to the reads going to the disk in that time period. But the quantum is very less.

[Active SStables read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pz43.jpg)

[Dashboard 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHwuC.png)

[Dashboard 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay3BM.png)

[Dashboard 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxosX.jpg)

[Dashboard 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntRjk.jpg)

[Dashbaord 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laV7X.jpg)

[Dashboard 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N4Qw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Read repair runs all the time, for every operation, if there is a discrepancy between the replicas, read-repair syncs the old one, just on a partition basis.

There is not enough data to figure out, it is probably compaction. Best to ask on the mailing list or slack. You can upload the compaction and the reactor graphs here.

Also, it's an obsolete version - move to 4.6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will update to the latest stable version. moreover, I have added more graphs. let me know if you can get any insight from those? and also should I change my compaction strategy to Leveled Compaction Strategy (LCS) from size tiered as my system is read heavy?